# Converting Swagger specification JSON to HTML documentation

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-php

For some REST APIs written in PHP, I was asked to create [Swagger](http://swagger.io) documentation, and since I was not aware of any easy way of annotating those existing APIs and create such a documentation, I used [this editor](http://editor.swagger.io/) to generate some for now.

I saved the JSON and YAML files created using that editor, and now I need to create the "interactive" Swagger documentation from there.

Can someone please let me know how I can convert the Swagger JSON specification file to an actual Swagger documentation?

I am on the Windows platform and do not know anything about Ant/Maven.

Comment: i tried [https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui](Swagger UI) but it is not rendering my json. the only warning shown is "This API is using a deprecated version of Swagger!  Please see http://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki for more info".

Answer (score 119, accepted):

**Update May 17, 2023**

Seems redoc-cli has been deprecated. so use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redocly/cli instead.  [Credit : @Dave]

Try to use **redoc-cli**.

I was using [bootprint-openapi](https://github.com/bootprint/bootprint-openapi) by which I was generating a bunch of files (`bundle.js`, `bundle.js.map`, `index.html`, `main.css` and `main.css.map`) and then you can convert it into a single `.html` file using [html-inline](https://github.com/substack/html-inline) to generate a simple `index.html` file.

Then I found [redoc-cli](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc#redoc-cli) very easy to to use and output is really-2 awesome, a **single and beautiful index.html** file.

**Installation**:

```
npm install -g redoc-cli
```

**Usage**:

```
redoc-cli bundle -o index.html swagger.json
```

Comment: This tool makes really the most beautiful output of all tools mentioned.

Comment: The generated all-in-one HTML file is quite big. So is the JS library dependency (~800KB) in the case that of live-rendering from custom HTML. Does anyone know how the size can be reduced?

Comment: This one is the best by far imo, and since we're building this for developers who are using desktops, the output size is a non-issue.

Comment: Using direct executable name not always works, execution by `npx redoc-cli ...` is more dependable.

Comment: wow. It took me under a minute to have all that doc in one file - on a Mac; is npm now built in? Thanks!

Comment: How can I add Request body properties in Swagger YAML?

Comment: small update: `redoc-cli` now wants you to use the `build` option instead of `bundle`.

Comment: Tried this and it told me it was deprecated, and to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redocly/cli instead.

Answer (score 48):

I was not satisfied with `swagger-codegen` when I was looking for a tool to do this, so I wrote my own. Have a look at [bootprint-swagger](https://github.com/nknapp/bootprint-swagger#overview)

The main goal compared to `swagger-codegen` is to provide an easy setup (though you'll need nodejs).
And it should be easy to adapt styling and templates to your own needs, which is a core functionality of the [bootprint](https://github.com/nknapp/bootprint)-project

Comment: Warning: As of 11/2016 the author of bootprint-swagger apparently has abandoned the project. swagger-codegen is still well supported.

Comment: I am the author and the text says: "I'm sorry to say that I won't be able to develop new features for this project in the near future. But: I will probably be able to discuss and merge pull-requests, and to publish new versions." You might call that abandoned, I would call it "on hold". I will also invite anyone who is interested in contributing to the project.

Comment: Found that `spectacle` generates much better-looking documentation from swagger JSON

Comment: Note to users checking this thread: SPECTACLE does not work anymore. npm installation results in error.

Answer (score 35):

Everything was too difficult or badly documented so I solved this with a simple script [swagger-yaml-to-html.py](https://gist.github.com/oseiskar/dbd51a3727fc96dcf5ed189fca491fb3), which works like this

```
python swagger-yaml-to-html.py < /path/to/api.yaml > doc.html
```

This is for YAML but modifying it to work with JSON is also trivial.

Comment: Also available as a docker now! https://github.com/yousan/swagger-yaml-to-html

Answer (score 28):

I spent a lot of time and tried a lot of different solutions - in the end I did it this way :

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@3.17.0/swagger-ui.css">
        <script src="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
        <script>

            function render() {
                var ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
                    url:  `path/to/my/swagger.yaml`,
                    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
                    presets: [
                        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
                        SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
                    ]
                });
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="render()">
        <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You just need to have *path/to/my/swagger.yaml* served from the same location.
(or use CORS headers)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I have used
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://petstore.swagger.io/swagger-ui.css">
    <script src="https://petstore.swagger.io/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.11.1/swagger-ui.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.11.1/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>

Answer (score 19):

Check out [pretty-swag](https://twskj.github.io/pretty-swag/)

It has

1. Similar looking as [Swagger-Editor](http://swagger.io/swagger-editor/)'s right panel
2. Search / Filter
3. Schema Folding
4. Live Feedback
5. Output as a single html file

I was looking at Swagger Editor and thought it could export the preview pane but turned out it cannot. So I wrote my own version of it.

Full Disclosure: I am the author of the tool.

Comment: I've found pretty-swag to be a straightforward and ideal tool, with appropriate CLI and API entry points.  My one and only complaint (and the one which forced me to deal with the complexity of swagger-ui instead) was its failure to correctly handle object composition/extension.  Any use of `allOf` in the document produces `undefined`, even in the simplest scenarios ("merging" a single object, equivalent to not using `allOf` at all).

Comment: Just rolled out `allOf` feature for you. Check it out.

Comment: Does not appear to support Swagger/OpenAPI V3

Answer (score 16):

See the [swagger-api/swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) project on GitHub ; the project README shows how to use it to generate static HTML. See [Generating static html api documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#generating-static-html-api-documentation).

If you want to view the swagger.json you can [install the Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and run it. You just deploy it on a web server (the dist folder after you clone the repo from GitHub) and view the Swagger UI in your browser. It's a JavaScript app.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was the swagger-ui was not accepting 2.0 spec. However, this looks like the simplest answer, so I will accept this (for now).

Comment: The Swagger tools are still evolving for 2.0. However, I've found Swagger UI does work for my 2.0 files that start with     "swagger": "2.0",

Comment: Also, from the Swagger Editor, you can export the JSON spec (not as YAML but as JSON) and the Swagger UI should be able to read that. (Note: the swagger.json must be on the same host/port as the Swagger UI app, or you must enable CORS; see the README.md in the Swagger Editor on GitHub

Answer (score 10):

You can also download swagger ui from: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui,
take the dist folder, modify index.html:
change the constructor

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: ...,
```

into

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    spec: YOUR_JSON,
```

now the dist folder contains all what you need and can be distributed as is

Comment: This approach was easiest for me.

Answer (score 7):

For Swagger API 3.0, generating Html2 client code  from online Swagger Editor works great for me!

Comment: None of the other suggestions worked for me, but this one did.  This was the simplest solution and worked very well.  Should be the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Do you mean this https://editor.swagger.io/?

Answer (score 4):

Redocly's [CLI interface](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/installation/) has a tool to build HTML docs from OpenAPI spec files.

```
sudo npm i -g @redocly/cli
redocly build-docs my-swagger.yml -o docs.html
```

Comment: redoc-cli is deprecated and now it's rebranded as redocly.

Answer (score 2):

Give a look at this link : http://zircote.com/swagger-php/installation.html

1. Download phar file https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/swagger.phar
2. Install Composer https://getcomposer.org/download/
3. Make composer.json
4. Clone swagger-php/library
5. Clone swagger-ui/library
6. Make Resource and Model php classes for the API
7. Execute the PHP file to generate the json
8. Give path of json in api-doc.json
9. Give path of api-doc.json in index.php inside swagger-ui dist folder

If you need another help please feel free to ask.

Comment: Is there an online editor (other than swagger-editor) that can generate this for me? I do not want to annotate my PHP APIs if there is a simpler way. The problem, I have figured out is that swagger-editor generates swagger spec v2.0, and swagger-ui does not handle that as of now.

Comment: @Salil all i know is that swagger provides it own on-line editor i.e. http://editor.swagger.wordnik.com/ i am not aware of any other on-line editor, if you find any share it with us, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you commit your JSON file in Gitlab, it will render it for you.

Comment: wow, that sounds nice. Wish they could do that 7 years, 2 months ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a small [Java program](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup) which generates docs (adoc or md) from a yaml file.

```
Swagger2MarkupConfig config = new Swagger2MarkupConfigBuilder()
        .withMarkupLanguage(MarkupLanguage.ASCIIDOC)
        .withSwaggerMarkupLanguage(MarkupLanguage.ASCIIDOC)
        .withOutputLanguage(Language.DE)
        .build();

Swagger2MarkupConverter builder = Swagger2MarkupConverter.from(yamlFileAsString).withConfig(config).build();
return builder.toFileWithoutExtension(outFile);
```

Unfortunately it only supports [OpenAPI 2.0](https://swagger.io/specification/v2/) but not [OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/3.0.0.md).

Answer (score 1):

I'm very happy with rapidoc : https://rapidocweb.com/

Why I liked it :

- Easy to use
- 'Try' option
- Possible to add code sample.
- Integration in other html page
- Possible to add css and change layout