# Generate static docs with swagger

Tags: swagger

Is there a method for creating static documentation for swagger 2.0?
Perhaps like the 'preview' on editor.swagger.io.

I need to get static html files so I can include them in some static documents.

So far I've not found a way to do this. I see there is swagger-codegens static-docs
but this only works for swagger <= 1.2.

Answer (score 47):

### Use swagger-codegen:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i <path to your swagger file> -l html2 -o <path to output location>
```

### If you decide to customize the HTML template:

1. Clone the swagger-codegen project from [github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)
2. Copy `modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/htmlDocs2` folder to another place, for example: `cp -R modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/htmlDocs2 ~/templates`
3. Modify the `.mustache` templates in `~/templates` to fit your requirements.
4. Run: `swagger-codegen generate -i <path to your swagger file> -l html2 -o <path to output location> -t <templates path>` for `<templates path>` should be `~/templates` in the example above.

Comment: Before running step 4, I had to install swagger-codegen by executing "brew install swagger-codegen" (Mac OS High Sierra)

Answer (score 21):

If you'd just like to generate static docs in a straightforward way, consider [Spectacle](https://github.com/sourcey/spectacle).

`npm install spectacle-docs` if you want to put a script in your `package.json`, or `npm install -g spectacle-docs` if it should be available everywhere.

Then you can just run `spectacle spec.yaml`, with options to build to a specific directory, run a server, and/or watch the specfile and update as needed.

Comment: Pls forgive beginner questions, what is spec.yaml and can it be generated by swagger? In my situation I only have annotations on Java endpoints managed by Spring, and the Swagger page appears magically. TIA

Comment: @chrisinmtown `spec.yaml` refers to the Swagger specification itself, which may be expressed in either JSON or YAML syntax.

Comment: Seems that the project is dead and doesn't support OpenAPI 3.0

Comment: Oh, thanks, you have no idea how much I wanted to know which tool build this doscs o/. DO you happen to know if we can add code samples using spectable?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `swagger-codegen` command as others have mentioned, but the output that you get from using `-l html` or `-l html2` is not interactive like the Swagger UI.

To get an *interactive* static page like the Swagger UI, follow these steps:

### Install

- Go to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases and download the latest release as a .zip file.
- Unzip the file and copy everything in the **./dist** folder over to the directory that you want the webserver to serve up.  For example, [Gitlab Pages](https://about.gitlab.com/product/pages/) needs it needs to be in the **./public** folder in your repository.
- Copy over your **swagger.yml** file to the **./public** folder.
- Open up the ./public/index.html file and update the URL to where the swagger file will be on the webserver.  For a local server, it might be this: `url: "http://localhost:8000/swagger.yml`

### Test

To test this out, you can run a simple HTTP server using python3.

`python3 -m http.server 8000 --directory public`

Open up http://localhost:8000/ and check it out!

Answer (score 7):

I usually do it with https://editor.swagger.io/. No installation or anything required.

Copy your yml file into the editor and choose 'Generate Client > html2' and it will generate static html files in a zip file.

Answer (score 6):

## OpenAPI 3

For rendering an OpenAPI 3 specification into self-contained HTML file, [redoc-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redoc-cli) can be used. You can use ReDoc's [Petstore OpenAPI 3 spec](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/master/demo/openapi.yaml) as example.

```
mkdir -p -m 777 build && docker run --rm --user 1000 \
  -v $PWD/build:/tmp/build -w /tmp/build \
  -v $PWD/openapi.yaml:/tmp/openapi.yaml node:14-slim npx -q \
  redoc-cli bundle /tmp/openapi.yaml
```

This will generate `build/redoc-static.html` in your current directory.

To avoid waiting for installation, you can also build yourself a Docker image with `redoc-cli` according to their [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/master/cli/Dockerfile), or installing `redoc-cli` to your OS, if you have NodeJS there, with `npm install -g redoc-cli`.

**Update:** there's actually a pre-built Docker image in [the project's GitHub Docker registry](https://github.com/redocly/redoc/pkgs/container/redoc%2Fcli), e.g. `ghcr.io/redocly/redoc/cli:v2.0.0-rc.76`.

## OpenAPI 2

ReDoc also has compatibility mode for OpenAPI 2/Swagger, so the above also works for [Petstore OpenAPI 2 spec](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/master/demo/swagger.yaml).

```
[ReDoc Compatibility mode]: Converting OpenAPI 2.0 to OpenAPI 3.0
```

Alternatively, the there's OpenAPI 2-only Spectacle and its official [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sourcey/spectacle). It can be used similarly like:

```
mkdir -p -m 777 build && docker run --rm --user 1000 \
  -v $PWD/build:/tmp/build \
  -v $PWD/swagger.yaml:/tmp/swagger.yaml sourcey/spectacle \
  spectacle -t /tmp/build /tmp/swagger.yaml
```

It generates static build which is almost self-contained (except loading jQuery from `code.jquery.com` which was slow for some reason on my end).

```
├── index.html
├── javascripts
│   ├── spectacle.js
│   └── spectacle.min.js
└── stylesheets
    ├── foundation.css
    ├── foundation.min.css
    ├── spectacle.css
    └── spectacle.min.css
```

Comment: I do now understand downvotes on this answer. It is the only one proposing to use redoc-cli and it works for me.

Comment: This is now [@redocly/cli](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/installation/) and I've found it both easier to use and better looking than swagger-ui.

Answer (score 5):

The static-docs in 2.0 is implemented for 2.0.  see the ./bin/static-docs.sh here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/bin

Comment: No static-docs.sh at that github link as of Apr 2018, pls amend?

Comment: I confirm there's no such script

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

- [swagger-ui](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/) : just git clone the project and copy your JSON in the base directory
- [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using OpenAPI Generator CLI Docker Image https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

it can generate server, clients and docs. for each language there are template files so you can modify the behaviour as needed

I managed to get a python-flask server generated and self hosting generated documentation.

the below will generate an html file that includes code examples for a client

```
USER=$(shell id -u)
GROUP=$(shell id -g)
MDIR=$(shell pwd)

docker run --rm --user ${USER} -u\:${GROUP} \
       -v ${MDIR}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
       --package-name EXAMPLE \
       -t /local/.openapi-generator-html-client/ \
       -i /local/EXAMPLE.v1.yaml \
       -g html2 \
       -o /local/openapi_docs
```

Answer (score 2):

If your specifically looking for for Swagger 2.0, I'd like to point you to my answer in 
[Converting Swagger specification JSON to HTML documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800493/converting-swagger-,specification-json-to-html-documentation/31096794#answer-31096794)
, although I believe that Swagger-Codegen supports Swagger 2.0 by now.

Answer (score 0):

Generating documentation is not actually necessary; all you need is an OpenAPI/Swagger file.

You can simply use `swagger-ui-dist` which consumes OpenAPI/Swagger file, this module exposes Swagger-UI's entire `dist` folder as a dependency-free npm module.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="SwaggerIU" />
    <title>SwaggerUI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://esm.sh/swagger-ui@4.19.0/dist/swagger-ui.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "swagger-ui-dist": "https://esm.sh/swagger-ui-dist@4.19.0/",
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Add your `url: <...>` to openapi file.

```js
// main.js

// @ts-check
import swagger from "swagger-ui-dist"

const ui = swagger.SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: 'https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json',
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
})
```

To enable autocomplete for `swagger-ui-dist`, you can initialize npm by running `npm init -y` and then install using `npm i -D @types/swagger-ui-dist`.

Answer (score -1):

"static" docs can mean several things.

If you're looking for an interactive display (like the editor's preview), you have swagger-ui (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui).

The code in the codegen that does the more static docs (without the "Try it now" button, for example) is not implemented yet for 2.0 though should be available in the upcoming few weeks.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's the 2.0 static-docs thing I needed so I guess I'll wait a few weeks.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure because swagger-editor's preview mode also has the ability to execute the operation and that's what you referred to in the original question.

Answer (score -4):

Include dependency for swagger in your pom.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And try hitting -> https://editor.swagger.io/