# swagger-codegen is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to configure swagger on my pc, so as to work with it. I am facing an issue with swagger-codegen is not recognized. This is the command I want to execute on command line:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i <path to your swagger file> -l html2 -o <path to output location> -t <templates path>
```

This is the source when I am based: [Generate static docs with swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605217/generate-static-docs-with-swagger/42115943#42115943)

Please help me!

Comment: Is it located in the working directory or in a directory contained in your PATH variable?

Comment: In a directory contained in my PATH variable. In fact I am not so sure

Comment: You can just check with `path` or `where swagger-codegen`

Comment: I don't know how to change the path

Comment: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\new\path`

Comment: I set path as you said but the same error still occurs

Comment: Have you tried it in the same cmd window or a new one? Try setting it permanently with `setx` or edit the variable in the registry.

Comment: I tried in a new cmd

Comment: I even tried with setx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, assuming that you downloaded the standalone *swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar* from here:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.2.2/swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar

you can run it as follows:

```
java -jar C:\path\to\swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l html2 -o C:\petstore\html2
```

Your original example is missing `java -jar`. Codegen is run via the Java launcher because it's a JAR file and not an standaline .exe file.

Comment: for path I need to add jar file path or swagger path?

Comment: It depends. If you use absolute paths, there's no need to change the `PATH`. If you want to use just the file names e.g. `-i petstore.json` or `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.2.jar`, add the folders containing these files.

Comment: I already face the problem swagger is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0):

Download Swagger Codegen from [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.36)[image: how to download]
For convert swagger to html: Write bottom code in cmd for get swagger.json file info from url and generate html code in intarface folder path:

```
java -jar {your downloaded above file, folder path}\swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.36.jar generate -i {your swagger web url}/swagger.json -l html2 -o {your output folder}
```

In my case is:

```
java -jar D:\Projects\swagger-codegen-master\swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.36.jar generate -i http://localhost:22293/swagger/v1/swagger.json -l html2 -o D:\Projects\swagger-codegen-master\interfaces
```

For convert swagger to angular classes:  Write bottom code in cmd for get swagger.json file info from url and generate angular code in intarface folder path:

```
java -jar {your downloaded above file, folder path}\swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.36.jar generate -i {your swagger web url}/swagger.json -l typescript-angular -o {your output folder}
```

In my case is:

```
java -jar D:\Projects\swagger-codegen-master\swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.36.jar generate -i http://localhost:22293/swagger/v1/swagger.json -l typescript-angular -o D:\Projects\swagger-codegen-master\interfaces
```

Here you are. Your APIs is ready to use in angular:
[image: converted Angular apis and models in VS code]