Generate offline docs for Swagger
I need to generate offline documentation (PDF / docx / Standalone html) for a Rest/Json api with a few constraint:

I don't have access to JVM or Docker
It needs to be reliable (no online site that could shutdown in the future)

Few extra infos: it's Uvnicorn server (Python3.9) generating openapi (3.0.2) jsonschema
The goal is to provide 1 document, that provide similar informations as SwaggerUI (each endpoints, with http codes, responses schemas, examples)
This document need to provide readable information without any extra tools (e.g. pdf is fine), my best attempt so far was to use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46484079/15719786
But there's still a bunch of imported scripts and ccs that either need seperated files or to be online

What did you try?  We would like to help you but we need details.  This is not a wish come true site.

What's your question?

See if this helps: How to generate a PDF or markup from OpenAPI 3.0?, How to generate offline Swagger API docs?, Swagger UI single interactive HTML. Also check this list of OpenAPI renderers: https://openapi.tools/#documentation, some of them can be self-hosted and/or viewed locally (e.g. Redoc, RapiDoc, Widdershins).

Also what's your use case? Do you want to self-host the API docs on your own site? Or ship the API docs as part of on-premise product installations? Or something else?

@Helen the goal is to provide a (hopefully) standalone, offline document, readable without any special tools (so HTML without imported script, PDF docx are fine) that provide similar information to swagger UI (endpoints, responses schemas, error code handlings...). My best attempt so far was to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/46484079/15719786 this python script -> open result in browser -> save as html -> this provides me 1 html with few other files (ccs and scripts) and work fine offline

You can use Redocly standalone html
download Redocly cli npm package.
npm install @redocly/cli:latest
Use the build-docs command to create a standalone html file
redocly build-docs <path/to/api> --output <filename.html>
lots of other customizations you can do with this command with the theme and config options.
src: https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/build-docs
